# Composition of natural transformations diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'd like to draw a diagram with tikz-cd for a composition of natural transformations between functors that looked like the following

[image]

The best I could do so far is given by the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
            \mathcal{A} \arrow[r, bend left=65, "F"]\arrow[r, "G", swap]\arrow[r, bend right=65, "H", swap] &   \mathcal{B}.
        \end{tikzcd} 
    \]
\end{document}
```

I'm wondering how to put G over the middle arrow and how to draw the vertical arrows `\alpha` and `\beta`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one option:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
    \mathcal{A}
     \arrow[r, bend left=65, "F"{name=F}]
     \arrow[r, "G"{inner sep=0,fill=white,anchor=center,name=G}]
     \arrow[r, bend right=65, "H"{name=H, swap}]
     \arrow[from=F.south-|G,to=G,Rightarrow,shorten=2pt,"\alpha"] 
     \arrow[from=G,to=H.north-|G,Rightarrow,shorten=2pt,"\beta"] &
   \mathcal{B}.
\end{tikzcd} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks perfect! But I get an error message: "I do not know the key to which you passed '2pt'..." and then "I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in 1-1".

Comment: @Vladimir Do you get that with the exact code in my answer?

Comment: Yes, with that exact code and nothing else.

Comment: @Vladimir Hm, don't really know why that would be. My only wild guess would be that you have an older version of `tikz-cd`. I have v0.9f. If you compile `\listfiles \documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz-cd} \begin{document} a \end{document}` you'll get a list of packages with their version numbers near the end of the `.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

This is my option. Now there is the vertical alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
\mathscr{A} \arrow[r, "F"{sloped,above},"\hspace{0.15cm}\scalebox{1.5}{$\Downarrow$} \alpha"{sloped,below}, bend left=70] \arrow[r, "\hspace{0.15cm}\scalebox{1.5}{$\Downarrow$} \beta", "H"{sloped,below}, bend right=70] \arrow[r, "G" description] & \mathscr{B}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Or with another package `\usepackage{scalerel}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
\mathscr{A} \arrow[r, "F"{sloped,above},"\hspace{0.15cm}\mathrel{\stretchto{\Downarrow}{2.6ex}} \alpha"{sloped,below}, bend left=65] \arrow[r, "\hspace{0.15cm}\mathrel{\stretchto{\Downarrow}{3ex}} \beta", "H"{sloped,below}, bend right=65] \arrow[r, "G" description] & \mathscr{B}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```